# MacBook Pro 2016 Orange Smudge on Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

My Mac has been having this problem lately with the display. Whenever I have it vertical in my backpack, it has an orange smudge (or line sometimes) somewhere on the screen when I open it up. The smudge disappears after sometime but reappears after having it my backpack again.

I've read some things on here, and I don't think its heat and I do not think it's a pressure mark. I do believe that the cause is having it vertical because when I opened it up today, it was the worst I've seen it so I did a test, I had it in my backpack, lying horizontally whenever possible for a few hours or so, and when I opened it up, it was nearly gone. I'm ruling out a pressure mark because all of my books and papers were lying on my Mac while it was in my bag horizontally.

I just do not know why having it vertical causes these smudges? I'm out of warranty so Apple is out of the question. Any suggestions or thoughts or whatnot?

Comment: Could you add a photo of the smudge to show what it looks like.

Comment: Even though it's a 4-year-old Mac, you may still have statutory rights, depending on your location. A genuine hardware defect may still require Apple to fix it. It's worth taking it to an Apple Shop and try to force the point, and see what they say.

Comment: When you have it in your backpack, is it in a special compartment that protects it or is it in betwixt other stuff like text books?  Im assuming you can’t wipe off the smudge because it’s inside the glass?  But, it goes away?

Comment: It's undoubtedly this: https://gregsamborski.com/macbook-pro-led-screen-discoloration-spots-15-2017-touch-bar/

A manufacturing defect that plaguing thousands of users.   Mine started occurring on mine 1.5 months after I bought it.   Now I have to power down completely and lie a piece of paper between the display and keyboard when I pack it to prevent the smudging.  

A totally normal thing to do when you "cheap out" with a $2500 laptop.